# Count unique tokens java

Tags: java, string, unique

I want to count unique characters in a string

Input:

```
"aabbccdefgh"
```

Output:

```
8
```

My code doesn't work and throws an error:

My code :

```
public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] s = {""};
    int counter = 0;
    int pom  = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length; i++){
        for(int y = 0; y < 128; y++){
            if(s[i].compareTo(args[y])>0){
                pom++;
            }
        }
    }
    while(pom == 1){
        counter++;
    }
    System.out.println(counter);
}
}
```

Could someone point out where I've gone wrong?

Comment: What's the error its giving you?

Comment: Your string array `s` is empty. Why?

Comment: ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error

Comment: Shouldn't it output `8` for your example? Just saying...

Comment: This will go into a never ending loop if pom is 1

Comment: I forget assign s , but when i assign it , it throw the same error

Comment: No , output is 5 , because , it count unique tokens . When token appear in word more then one , it isn't consider .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aabbccdefgh";
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.substring(0, i).contains(str.charAt(i) + ""))
            System.out.println();

        else
            count++;
    }
    System.out.println(count);

}
```

Try this without using set .

Comment: Yes , it work . But it give result 8 . if tokens duplicate it count it as one , but it shouldn't count it . result of your example must be 5 .

Comment: @MtbSpec Ok , You want to count the characters whose occurrence is only once in the given string ...yes?

Answer (score 3):

Use a `Set`. It will ensure uniqueness, so after you've added each character the size of the set will be your answer.

Comment: I use a set in my second solution , but i must do it with tabs too .

Answer (score 2):

Why don't use `Set` to count unique number of tokens?

```
String str = "aabbccdefgh";
HashSet<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();    

for (int i=0; i < str.length; i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    set.put(c);
}

System.out.println(set.size());
```

Comment: I do it with set firstly , but i need more solutions . And solution with tab , is one with i need .

Answer (score 1):

I believe the root cause of the error is this piece of code:

```
for(int y = 0; y < 128; y++){
    if(s[i].compareTo(args[y])>0){
        pom++;
    }
}
```

Specifically, the comparison on `args[y]` inside the loop.  The code above assumes that you pass at least 128 parameters to your java program when invoking it, i.e.

```
java test param0 param1 ... param127
```

And I'm pretty sure that you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Now that you know the cause, use [@Kevin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14124604/717214) to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since the task is to count only those characters that occur once in the string, use a `Map<Character, Integer>` to count the character frequencies.  Otherwise the logic is pretty much shown in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "aabbccdefgh";

    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        Integer count = map.get(str.charAt(i));
        if (count == null)
            map.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
        else
            map.put(str.charAt(i), count + 1);
    }

    int uniqueCount = 0;

    for (Integer i : map.values())
        if (i == 1)
            uniqueCount++;

    System.out.println(uniqueCount);

}
```

Here is the another answer which will count the occurrence of characters whose occurrence is only once in the given string using Map.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the number of characters that are unique , set is not an option since set includes the repeated character once . for example , "galaxy" should return 4 but using set , it will return 5 since 'a' will also be included

Answer (score 0):

If you are already in Java 8, use the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(countDistinctCharacters("aabbccdefgh"));
}

public static long countDistinctCharacters(String letter) {
    return letter.chars().distinct().count();
}
```